# Converting process for dwg plan

Tags: qgis

I work for an train enterprise and we want to develop a SIG. The main goal is better property management. The main data to manage are dwg plans. My job is to write a process to introduce this plan in a SIG (QGIS). How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you mention what kind of data is contained in these DWG files. The issue might be more than just a simple conversion, especially when you have parcel data, and want to end up with polygons. Your data will most likely require topology checking and some editing before it becomes valid GIS data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with dwg, you need to give coordinates (longitude / latitude) to your "picture" (dwg). Some GIS use functionality to project a picture on coordinate plan. 
For example : http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html.
ArcGIS can read DWG format but you should do georeferencing too. Try with QGIS.

Later, use the georeferenced picture to draw (digitize) some of your objects on the new raster support which is the DWG with coordinates system (raster = picture or imagery).

Comment: see this link : 
to convert DWG to shape => https://www.gisconvert.com/